Linear Regression switch in sign when including intercept
I am running a simple regression of y on x. When I include the intercept the beta for x is negative and significant and when I don't include the intercept the beta is positive and significant. What to infer from this?
There are similar questions on this forum when using other variables, but I could not find anything using only the intercept.

Welcome to Cross Validated! Have you plotted your data?

It would also be helpful to see your model output for both. Are you able to include it in your question?

@acooper please include the requested information (plots and regression output /summary). It's likely to lead to more suitable responses

I expect both your variables have a positive mean, making the no-intercept slope positive despite the negative relationship between the variables.
Like so:

By being forced through the origin the orange line ignores any relationship between the variables, and just passes  through a point near the middle of the x,y cloud. Since one point on the line  must be at (0,0) it can't do any better
(Feel free to skip this last part since it's mostly editorializing. It does have some warnings that might useful to some readers.) This is a situation I see often in my line of work.
Convincing people to stop using a fit through the origin that simply doesn't fit can be difficult $-$ though in the case I run into, the problems with that very commonly used model are manifold $-$ simply introducing an intercept doesn't fix the other issues with that situation (substantial omitted-variable bias, using cumulated data which introduces very strong time dependence while treating it as independent, unmodelled but severe heteroskedasticity or completely unsuitable choices of model for it, unsuitable distributional model choices, uninformative choices of model diagnostics $-$ you name it).
Many people in that area tend to either ignore the issues, or keep tweaking the underlying but fundamentally flawed idea $-$ but no matter how much glitter you throw at it, it still doesn't work. When you do get people who are very attached to this idea  to think outside that particularly small box, it's usually only to replace those models with other highly flawed ones. The basic unavoidable properties of the variables involved still remain $-$ reality bends not one whit for flawed paradigms or strong cultural imperatives. Sometimes you just have to recognize that the universe really doesn't work the way you might like to think.

+1 but do note the way R software calculates $R^2$ when there is no intercept and that it will not catch the terrible fit by the orange line.

Yeah that's a good point. The use of $R^2$ is certainly a problem when you don't have a null (0 slope) model that passes through the mean of y (which $R^2$ uses on the denomnator). Much can be written about issues with $R^2$ in that situation.

A search here for the relevant terms should bring up lots of discussion of that specific issue

Incidentally, with my data above both  the $R^2$ values produced by R are high (and rerunning my code I get 0.8 to 0.9 across multiple simulations) and the no intercept one is nearly always a bit larger (despite the model being very poor). R^2 isn't useful for this and the two sets of values are not comparable.

Yeah, OK, but we don't know anything about the appropriateness of the model, the regression type, the residuals, or the physics of the problem, so the question itself is incomplete to the point of tears.

First, regression without an intercept is best called "forcing the intercept through 0".  Is your intercept fairly large?  By dropping the intercept you are perhaps forcing it far from where it wants to be.  (However, it seems odd that the slope would be significant in both cases).
If your intercept is close to 0 already, it does seem odd that the sign of the slope would flip.  But...
Second, running a regression without an intercept is pretty rare.  Even if you have theoretical reasons for thinking the intercept is (0,0) and/or (0,0) is a relevant value in the data, things often get nonlinear as they get closer to 0 if 0 is the lowest value the data can take.
I don't have a reason for it, just intuition, but trying a log transformation  or centering the data at 0 may help you understand what's up.  In general though don't drop the intercept unless you have strong justification is the advice I've seen multiple times.

"However, it seems odd that the slope would be significant in both cases" ... this situation occurs very easily. Both slopes on the plot  in my answer had p values on their slope coefficient below $2.2\times 10^{-16}$
